# JavaScript Quiz Valadition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be having some trouble validating a 4 question multiple choice quiz in JavaScript. Right now if none of the answers are selected the alert pops up, but if even only one answer is selected the alert doesn't pop. I'm running my function as an onclick for a submit button. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and JQuery but have other programming experience, so The problem is probably something simple but I cant see it.
The function is:

```
function quiz1(){

    if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q2]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q3]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q4]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q5]:checked").val()
        ) {
        alert("You're not done yet!");
    }
}
```

The html is:

```
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">2. What is the answer to this question?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">Answer 4</label><br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">3. What is the answer to this question?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">Answer 4</label><br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">4. What is the answer to this question?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c"><label for="q4c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d"><label for="q4d">Answer 4</label><br/>
</ul>

<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" onclick="quiz1()" value="Check Answers">
</div>
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was apparently using the wrong syntax for the selector. Either the @ is not a valid selector or it is outdated. Sometimes just asking the question gives you the answer because this has been driving me nuts for a day and a half, and I figured it out 30 minutes after posting. Thanks for the great community here. I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question for 8 hours so I'll post the working code and an official answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in there.

before:

```
function quiz1(){

    if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q2]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q3]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q4]:checked").val() ||
        !$("input[@name=q5]:checked").val()
        ) {
        alert("You're not done yet!");
    }
}
```

After:

```
function quiz1(){

  if (!$("input[name='q1']:checked").val() ||
      !$("input[name='q2']:checked").val() ||
      !$("input[name='q3']:checked").val() ||
      !$("input[name='q4']:checked").val()
      ) {
      alert("You're not done yet!");
  }
```

}

so with jquery when you want to reference a name you have to type it just like the name attribute in the html that is true with any attribute selector E.G.(data='', ng-someting=''...) and also you had one to many inputs in there XD

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/fxq99heo/)

Comment: If you look at the comments in the question I saw that already and fixed it. I was going to post the answer myself but don't have enough reputation yet so I'll vote yours since it's the same solution and maybe it will help others. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ha didn't even see that. well thanks for the rep :-)